# How to get a std::list<T>::iterator from an element of that list?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, iterator

Given a std:: list

```
std::list< int > myList
```

and a reference (or a pointer) to an element in that list

```
int& myElement    |     int* pElement
```

So, basically I know the address of that element

How can I get an `std::list<int>::iterator` to that element efficiently?

A slow yet working example is

```
const_iterator it
for( it = myList.begin(); it != &myElement; ++it)
{
    // do nothing, for loop terminates if "it" points to "myElem"
}
```

Is there a quicker way? like

```
const_iterator it = magicToIteratorConverter( myList, myElem )
```

### Case of vector (but I need list):

For a vector, you could do the following:

```
const int* pStart = &myVector[0] // address of first element
const int* pElement = &myElem; // address of my element
const idx = static_cast< int >( pElement- pStart ); // no need to divide by size of an elem

std::vector< int >::iterator it = myVector.begin() + idx;
```

### Case of std::list:

Comment: Your "slow and working" example does not work in general.

Comment: `std::find` maybe?

Comment: So what exactly is myElement? You did not show its type.

Comment: Also, this is logically not possible as `myElement` may occur in the list more than once.

Comment: doesn't std::find, need to iterate through the container?

Comment: myElement is simply "int"

Comment: The only way is to iterate through the container and compare the addresses.  Unless you can guarantee that only unique values exist.

Comment: @S.H yes, it works with `O(n)` worst case for `std::list`, while achieving `O(1)` for `std::vector`.

Comment: Why can't I convert from the element and its address to an iterator?

Comment: @S.H because that's not how lists work, unfortunately.

Comment: If myElement  is an int the list only contains a copy.

Comment: @manni66: Sorry, my question was no specific enough, I have a *reference* (or, if you want, pointer) to that element. I edited the question

Comment: @iehrlich: How is O(1) achieved with `std::vector`?

Comment: Are you sure you need `std::list`? I think you need `std::vector` to achieve what you want.

Comment: If you can hold a referrence to the list entry why can't you store the iterator?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `v.begin() + (&element - &v[0])`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit at this point, I confused myself :) O(1) might be achieved when re-constructing an iterator from the *pointer* to an element, not from the *value* of an element.

Comment: @iehrlich: Oh yes indeed. Was also thinking of value lookup :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: exactly, and now for a list, that'd be great :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Of course, if the element _isn't_ in the container, that's UB. In fact, frankly, since a vector's contents are individually placement new'd into a big `char` buffer, I'm not even convinced this pointer arithmetic is valid (it's not navigating around "the same object")

Comment: @S.H. : Can't be done. I'd suggest you take a look at where you got the reference to the element in the first place. Because wherever that was, it started out as an iterator. So if you needed an iterator in the first place, why'd you discard it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Legacy code...

Comment: Well then you've either got to rewrite it, or stick with the O(n) algorithm. Because what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: `s/Legacy/bad/` ;)

Comment: It is likely doable if you break into the implementation of `list`, which is never a good idea

Comment: upvoted because of downvotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a good question and IMHO a shame that there is no std way to do what OP has asked. If you understand that a list node looks essentially like this

```
struct list_node {
    list_node* prev;
    list_node* next;
    T yourType;
}
```

it is bad that there is no default way to get to the node (the iterator is a pointer to the node) if you have a pointer to `yourType` without searching through the whole container.

---

Since std is not helping you have to get your hands dirty:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

//This is essentially what you are looking for:
std::list<int>::iterator pointerToIter (int* myPointer) {
    //Calculates the distance in bytes from an iterator itself
    //to the actual type that is stored at the position the
    //iterator is pointing to.
    size_t iterOffset = (size_t)&(*((std::list<void*>::iterator)nullptr));
    //Subtract the offset from the passed pointer and make an
    //iterator out of it
    std::list<int>::iterator iter;
    *(intptr_t*)&iter = (intptr_t)myPointer - iterOffset;
    //You are done
    return iter;
}

int main () {
    std::list<int> intList;
    intList.push_back (10);
    int* i1 = &intList.back ();
    intList.push_back (20);
    intList.push_back (30);
    int* i3 = &intList.back ();
    intList.push_back (40);
    intList.push_back (50);
    int* i5 = &intList.back ();

    std::cout << "Size: " << intList.size () << " | Content: ";
    for (const int& value : intList)
        std::cout << value << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    intList.erase (pointerToIter (i1));
    intList.erase (pointerToIter (i3));
    intList.erase (pointerToIter (i5));

    std::cout << "Size: " << intList.size () << " | Content: ";
    for (const int& value : intList)
        std::cout << value << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (to prove that it works as intended):

> Size: 5 | Content: 10 20 30 40 50
>   Size: 2 | Content: 20 40

This works perfectly even if an implementation of std::list would use a different layout for the list-node or add some more members to it. I also included the assembler code generated to see that the function is essentially reduced to `myPointer - 0x10` (`0x10 = 16` is the size of 2 pointers on a 64bit machine).

Assembler (with at least -O1):

```
std::list<int>::iterator pointerToIter (int* myPointer) {
   0:   48 8d 47 f0             lea    rax,[rdi-0x10]
}
   4:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: MSVC refuses to compile your function: `error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>'`

Answer (score 6):

a `std::list<int>::iterator` is not an `int*`, you need to access the element in the iterator and get its address.  Also, `std::find_if` takes care of most of the boilerplate for you.

```
auto iter = std:find_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(),
                        [&myElement](const int & listElement)
                        { return &myElement == &listElement; });
```

Writing the loop out yourself would look like:

```
auto iter = myList.end();

for(auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); ++i)
    if(&*i == &myElement)
    {
        iter = i;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Here's an interesting question - are we absolutely guaranteed that `listElement` will be a reference to the same object that's stored in the container?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know this was discussed at length somewhere here.  I seem to recall that the conclusion was that the standard does not guarantee it, however most people don't seem bothered by that.

Comment: Just looked at C++14 25.2.5/1 and it seems yes we are

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure I understand your question since I don't see how your standard quote answers the question.

Comment: It says: _"The first iterator i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false, pred(*i) == false"_ and _"At most last - first applications of the corresponding predicate."_ This means (I think) that all invocations of your predicate must be given the result of dereferencing an iterator from the container (and such a result is always a reference to the actual element). It means your answer is correct even at the super-nitpick level: congrats!

Comment: Okay technically I suppose there could be _last - result_ spurious invocations that give your predicate a reference to some arbitrary local `int`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ah, I see you meant whether `std::find` creates copies before passing the value to the predicate, which intuitively makes sense that algorithms try to avoid that whenever they can

Comment: That's the badger. Don't get me wrong, I can't see a reason any implementation would actually do this. But I like to be sure ;) (although if we're to be _entirely_ sure we have to look at the source code, because bugs happen and not all impls even pretend to be word-for-word compliant in the first place!)

Answer (score 2):

Given a list, you can only get to anything by starting from one end walking through it, making sure you don't go beyond the end.

```
const_iterator it, end;
for( it = myList.begin(), end = myList.end(); it!=end && it != &myElement; ++it)
{
    // do nothing, for loop terminates if "it" points to "myElem"
      // or if we don't find your element.
}
```

Of course, you could use a standard algorithm, like [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to look for it.

Alternatively, you could keep hold of the iterator when you insert, and under many conditions it will still be valid later on.

If you want lookup speed, you should probably use something other than a list.

---

If you have something like

```
int x = 42;
int * this_might_be_handy = &x;
myList.insert(x);
```

myList now has a COPY of the number - it has the value 42, but in a different memory location.

If you kept pointers to ints in the list, that would be different. getting the value from the `front` of the list and looking at the address will not give the same address as `x`.

But you would have to manage them smartly.

Comment: What if I know the address of the element?

Comment: `it != &myElement` Are you sure that works?  I don't think there is any requirement for the value of the iterator to be the address of the object.  I think `&(*it) != &myElement` would be more correct.

Comment: @S.H: This answer shows you how to get from the address of the element to an iterator of the node.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `!=` but yes

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know that I can use `it != &myElement´, but I can't use `std::list<int>::iterator = &myElem´. And that's just what I need

Comment: @S.H. Tough cookies :) This is why we shall not mix pointers and iterators. Slap the original dev

Answer (score 1):

This is a dissected, formalized (C++11) and commented version of the very interesting solution of Xatian above. That solution is O(1) (that is one of the reasons it is so interesting), but it assumes some things that should be taken into account (Xatian's deep knowledge of the STL implementation of lists is the other reason why it is so interesting).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
{
    // ASSUMPTIONS:

    //  1.- nullptr == 0
    //  2.- A std::list iterator is an object that contains just one thing: a pointer to the body of the iterator.
    //  3.- A std::list iterator has a constructor that admits a pointer to a body provided by the user, which creates the iterator with that (assumed) existing body.


    using DataType = int;
    using DataList = std::list<DataType>;

    std::cout << "Nullptr= " << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(nullptr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of a pointer = " << sizeof(nullptr) << ", size of iterator = " << sizeof(DataList::iterator) << std::endl;

    static_assert(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(nullptr) == 0,
                "In this compiler, nullptr is not 0 and this will not work");


    // we have a list filled with something.
    DataList mylist{1,2,3,4};
    // and an iterator pointing to some data.
    DataList::iterator itaux{mylist.begin()};
    ++itaux;
    ++itaux;


    // 1. calculate the offset of the data in a list iterator w.r.t. the beginning of the iterator body

    DataList::iterator it{nullptr}; // call the iterator constructor. Nullptr becomes the address of the body where the iterator would store prev/next/data
                                // since nullptr is assumed to be 0, this is the same as to declare an iterator with its body at 0x00000000
    DataType & itp = *it; // this is a reference to the user's data in the iterator body
                      // that iterator is a fake and does not contain any data, but since we are only dealing with addresses, no problem...
    DataType * aitp = & itp; // this gets the address equivalent to the reference, which is at some point in memory from 0
    size_t iteroffset = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(aitp); // That address becomes, actually, the offset of the data w.r.t. the beginning of the iterator body

    std::cout << "Offset from iterator body start to data = " << iteroffset << std::endl;


    // 2. we can get the pointer to the data from our existing iterator
    DataType * mypointer = &(*itaux);

    // 3. we can create a valid iterator from the pointer to the data
    DataList::iterator iter;
    *(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t*>(&iter)) = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(mypointer) - iteroffset; // the address of the beginning of the body (mypointer-iteroffset) is stored into 
                                                                                                // the pointer to the body that the iterator actually is

    std::cout << "pointed element: " << (*iter) << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```